# Webtechnick CakePHP-Facebook-Plugin have to request twice to recognize logged user

Tags: php, facebook, cakephp, authentication

i am using the CakePHP-Facebook-Plugin from webtechnick (https://github.com/webtechnick/CakePHP-Facebook-Plugin/) and i am having some trouble with recognizing if the user is already logged in on facebook. The problem is: i log in to facebook, then i open my website (localhost.localdomain) and i am not logged in. Then i refresh my website page and i am logged in.
Above is the code i am using. I've tested it and in first request, the $this->Connect->user() call returns false (the first and the second ones), then the page is rendered and i think some magic is done by the init or the FacebookHelper->login method, because if i call it without a redirect, it says i am online and using my website; with the redirect set, it shows the label and on the second request i got logged in.

I've tried to initialize the FacebookHelper and call "login" on beforeFilter, but no success (with and without the redirect).

Also, the logic to show facebooks's login or logout buttons is done further in the beforeFilter, defining an specific layout based on the value of $this->Session->check('Auth.User.id').

```
27     public function beforeFilter() {
28 
29         try {
30             $user = $this->Auth->user();
31             $fb_user = $this->Connect->user();
32         } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
33         } 
34         Configure::write('VertWeb.show_tabs', true);
35         if ($fb_user = $this->Connect->user()) {
36             if (!$this->Auth->loggedIn()) {
37                 if (!isset($fb_user['error_code'])) {
38                     $this->loadModel('User');
39                     $this->User->recursive = -1;
40                     if (($user = $this->User->findByFacebookId($fb_user['id'])) ||
41                         ($user = $this->User->findByEmail($fb_user['email'])) ) {
42                         
43                         $this->Auth->login($user);
44                         $this->Session->write('Auth.FacebookUser', $fb_user);
45                         $this->Session->write('Auth.User', $user['User']);
46                         $this->Session->write('Auth.FacebookUserPicture', FB::api('/me?fields=picture'));
```

Kind regards,
Daniel

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue to, I fix it puting this lines in Initialize (and remove startup method)

```
if (!$this->noAuth && !empty($this->uid)) {
     $this->__syncFacebookUser();
}
```